# linq related question

Tags: c#, linq, deep-copy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Comparer.csd
{
    class Program
    {
        /* Confusion is regarding how ToList() method works. Does it do the deep copy or shallow copy??

        /**********OUTPUT
         a a b
         a b c
         a c a
        -----------------
         a a b
         a c a
        -----------------
        1
        2
        3
        OUTPUT ENDS************/

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<test> list = new List<test>();
            list.Add(new test("a", "b", "c"));
            list.Add(new test("a", "c", "a"));
            list.Add(new test("a", "a", "b"));

            /// sort the list based on first name and last name

            IEnumerable<test> soretedCollection = from t in list
                                     orderby t._fname ascending, t._mname ascending
                                     select t;
            Print(soretedCollection);
            /// remove the first object from the list
            list.RemoveAt(0);
            /// print the list .
            /// Removal of the item from the list is reflected here so I guess sorted collection and list both 
            /// are refering the same data structure
            /// what if I will do 
            /// list = soretedCollection.ToList<test>(); /// is it going to change the reference of the list if some other object 
            /// is holding the reference??
            Print(soretedCollection);

            Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();            
            dic.Add(1, 1);
            dic.Add(2, 1);
            dic.Add(3, 1);
            List<int> keys = dic.Keys.ToList<int>();
            /// remove the dictionary entry with key=2
            dic.Remove(2);
            /// how come this time it did not remove the second item becuase it is removed from the dictionary.
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(keys[i].ToString());
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void Print(IEnumerable<test> list)
        {
            foreach (test t in list)
            {
                t.Print();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `.ToList()` forces **eager** execution of the full enumeration - the result of this is a separate list from the original enumeration, so any changes after `.ToList()` won't be reflected in that list. The actual items in this list are the same (same object references) as in the original enumeration as @Johannes Rudolph pointed out - so yes that's a shallow copy.

The `IEnumerable<test>` though will be **lazily** executed over the source collection - only when you actively enumerate the items  (i.e. by using `foreach` or `.ToList()`) will the enumeration create an Enumerator that takes the source collection as it is at that point in time - that means if there are changes in the underlying collection before the Enumerator is created these will be reflected in the enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

`ToList` will always create a shallow copy of your list, that is the returned list will reference the *same* objects as your source `IEnumerable` does, but the List returned is a copy of the source.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx).